# Find details of SyntaxError thrown by javascript new Function() constructor

Tags: javascript

When creating new function from JavaScript code using new Function(params,body) constructor, passing invalid string in body yelds SyntaxError. While this exception contains error message (ie: `Unexpected token =`), but does not seem to contain context (ie. line/column or character where error was found).

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gheh1m8p/

```
var testWithSyntaxError = "{\n\n\n=2;}";

try {
    var f=new Function('',testWithSyntaxError);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e instanceof SyntaxError); 
  console.log(e.message);               
  console.log(e.name);                
  console.log(e.fileName);            
  console.log(e.lineNumber);           
  console.log(e.columnNumber);         
  console.log(e.stack);               
}
```

Output:

```
true
(index):54 Unexpected token =
(index):55 SyntaxError
(index):56 undefined
(index):57 undefined
(index):58 undefined
(index):59 SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Function (native)
    at window.onload (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:51:8)
```

**How can I, without using external dependencies, pinpoint SyntaxError location withinn passed string?** I require solution both for browser and nodejs.

Please note: I do have a valid reason to use eval-equivalent code.

Comment: I think it depends on a browser, you can make a feature request. But if you need advanced syntax analysis, it is very easy to make one using PEG.js .

Comment: Is there an expected answer for this (e.g. for a homework assignment)?

Comment: [error.lineNumber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/lineNumber) is non-standard and implemented only in Firefox => you will have to parse the string manually

Answer (score 5):

In Chromium-based browsers, as you've seen, putting `try`/`catch` around something that throws a SyntaxError while V8 is *parsing* the code (before actually running it) won't produce anything helpful; it will describe the line that *caused the evaluation* of the problematic script in the stack trace, but no details on where the problem was in said script.

But, there's a cross-browser workaround. Instead of using `try`/`catch`, you can add an `error` listener to `window`, and the first argument provided to the callback will be an `ErrorEvent` which has useful `lineno` and `colno` properties:

```js
window.addEventListener('error', (errorEvent) => {
  const { lineno, colno } = errorEvent;
  console.log(`Error thrown at: ${lineno}:${colno}`);
  // Don't pollute the console with additional info:
  errorEvent.preventDefault();
});

const checkSyntax = (str) => {
  // Using setTimeout because when an error is thrown without a catch,
  // even if the error listener calls preventDefault(),
  // the current thread will stop
  setTimeout(() => {
    eval(str);
  });
};

checkSyntax(`console.log('foo') bar baz`);
checkSyntax(`foo bar baz`);
```

```html
Look in your browser console to see this in action, not in the snippet console
```

Check the results in your browser console:

```
Error thrown at: 1:20
Error thrown at: 1:5
```

Which is what we want! Character 20 corresponds to

```
console.log('foo') bar baz
                       ^
```

and character 5 corresponds to

```
foo bar baz
    ^
```

There are a couple issues, though: it would be good to make sure in the `error` listened for is an error thrown when running `checkSyntax`. Also, `try`/`catch` *can* be used for runtime errors (including syntax errors) *after* the script text has been parsed into an AST by the interpreter. So, you might have `checkSyntax` *only* check that the Javascript is initially parsable, and nothing else, and *then* use `try/catch` (if you want to run the code for real) to catch runtime errors. You can do this by inserting `throw new Error` to the top of the text that's `eval`ed.

Here's a convenient Promise-based function which can accomplish that:

```js
// Use an IIFE to keep from polluting the global scope
(async () => {
  let stringToEval;
  let checkSyntaxResolve;
  const cleanup = () => {
    stringToEval = null;
    checkSyntaxResolve = null; // not necessary, but makes things clearer
  };
  window.addEventListener('error', (errorEvent) => {
    if (!stringToEval) {
      // The error was caused by something other than the checkSyntax function below; ignore it
      return;
    }
    const stringToEvalToPrint = stringToEval.split('\n').slice(1).join('\n');
    // Don't pollute the console with additional info:
    errorEvent.preventDefault();
    if (errorEvent.message === 'Uncaught Error: Parsing successful!') {
      console.log(`Parsing successful for: ${stringToEvalToPrint}`);
      checkSyntaxResolve();
      cleanup();
      return;
    }
    const { lineno, colno } = errorEvent;
    console.log(`Syntax error thrown at: ${lineno - 1}:${colno}`);
    console.log(describeError(stringToEval, lineno, colno));
    // checkSyntaxResolve should *always* be defined at this point - checkSyntax's eval was just called (synchronously)
    checkSyntaxResolve();
    cleanup();
  });

  const checkSyntax = (str) => {
    console.log('----------------------------------------');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      checkSyntaxResolve = resolve;
      // Using setTimeout because when an error is thrown without a catch,
      // even if the 'error' listener calls preventDefault(),
      // the current thread will stop
      setTimeout(() => {
        // If we only want to check the syntax for initial parsing validity,
        // but not run the code for real, throw an error at the top:
        stringToEval = `throw new Error('Parsing successful!');\n${str}`;
        eval(stringToEval);
      });
    });
  };
  const describeError = (stringToEval, lineno, colno) => {
    const lines = stringToEval.split('\n');
    const line = lines[lineno - 1];
    return `${line}\n${' '.repeat(colno - 1) + '^'}`;
  };

  await checkSyntax(`console.log('I will throw') bar baz`);
  await checkSyntax(`foo bar baz will throw too`);
  await checkSyntax(`console.log('A snippet without compile errors'); const foo = bar;`);
  await checkSyntax(`console.log('A multi line snippet');
With a syntax error on the second line`);
})();
```

```html
Look in your browser console to see this in action, not in the snippet console
```

```
await checkSyntax(`console.log('I will throw') bar baz`);
await checkSyntax(`foo bar baz will throw too`);
await checkSyntax(`console.log('A snippet without compile errors'); const foo = bar;`);
await checkSyntax(`console.log('A multi line snippet');
With a syntax error on the second line`);
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------------
Syntax error thrown at: 1:29
console.log('I will throw') bar baz
                            ^
----------------------------------------
Syntax error thrown at: 1:5
foo bar baz will throw too
    ^
----------------------------------------
Parsing successful for: console.log('A snippet without compile errors'); const foo = bar;
----------------------------------------
Syntax error thrown at: 2:6
With a syntax error on the second line
     ^
```

If the fact that an error is thrown at `window` is a problem (for example, if something else is already listening for window errors, which you don't want to disturb, and you can't attach your listener first and call `stopImmediatePropagation()` on the event), another option is to use a web worker instead, which has its own execution context completely separate from the original `window`:

```js
// Worker:
const getErrorEvent = (() => { 
  const workerFn = () => {
    const doEvalAndReply = (jsText) => { 
      self.addEventListener(
        'error', 
        (errorEvent) => { 
          // Don't pollute the browser console:
          errorEvent.preventDefault();
          // The properties we want are actually getters on the prototype;
          // they won't be retrieved when just stringifying
          // so, extract them manually, and put them into a new object:
          const { lineno, colno, message } = errorEvent;
          const plainErrorEventObj = { lineno, colno, message };
          self.postMessage(JSON.stringify(plainErrorEventObj));
        },
        { once: true }
      );
      eval(jsText);
    };
    self.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
      doEvalAndReply(e.data);
    });
  };
  const blob = new Blob(
    [ `(${workerFn})();`],
    { type: "text/javascript" }
  );
  const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  // Use a queue to ensure processNext only calls the worker once the worker is idle
  const processingQueue = [];
  let processing = false;
  const processNext = () => {
    processing = true;
    const { resolve, jsText } = processingQueue.shift();
    worker.addEventListener(
      'message',
      ({ data }) => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        if (processingQueue.length) {
          processNext();
        } else {
          processing = false;
        }
      },
      { once: true }
    );
    worker.postMessage(jsText);
  };
  return (jsText) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    processingQueue.push({ resolve, jsText });
    if (!processing) {
      processNext();
    }
  });
})();


// Calls worker:
(async () => {
  const checkSyntax = async (str) => {
    console.log('----------------------------------------');
     const stringToEval = `throw new Error('Parsing successful!');\n${str}`;
     const { lineno, colno, message } = await getErrorEvent(stringToEval);
     if (message === 'Uncaught Error: Parsing successful!') {
       console.log(`Parsing successful for: ${str}`);
       return;
     }
    console.log(`Syntax error thrown at: ${lineno - 1}:${colno}`);
    console.log(describeError(stringToEval, lineno, colno));
  };
  const describeError = (stringToEval, lineno, colno) => {
    const lines = stringToEval.split('\n');
    const line = lines[lineno - 1];
    return `${line}\n${' '.repeat(colno - 1) + '^'}`;
  };

  await checkSyntax(`console.log('I will throw') bar baz`);
  await checkSyntax(`foo bar baz will throw too`);
  await checkSyntax(`console.log('A snippet without compile errors'); const foo = bar;`);
  await checkSyntax(`console.log('A multi line snippet');
With a syntax error on the second line`);
})();
```

```html
Look in your browser console to see this in action, not in the snippet console
```

Essentially, what `checkSyntax` is doing is checking to see if the code provided can be parsed into an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://itnext.io/ast-for-javascript-developers-3e79aeb08343) *by the current interpreter*. You can also use packages like [@babel/parser](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser) or [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) to attempt to parse the string, though you'll have to configure it for the syntax permitted in the current environment (which will change as new syntax gets added to the language).

```js
const checkSyntax = (str) => {
  try {
    acorn.Parser.parse(str);
    console.log('Parsing successful');
  } catch(e){
    console.error(e.message);
  }
};

checkSyntax(`console.log('I will throw') bar baz`);
checkSyntax(`foo bar baz will throw too`);
checkSyntax(`console.log('A snippet without compile errors'); const foo = bar;`);
checkSyntax(`console.log('A multi line snippet');
With a syntax error on the second line`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/acorn@6.1.1/dist/acorn.min.js"></script>
```

The above works for *browsers*. In Node, the situation is different: listening for an [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) can't be used to intercept the details of syntax errors, AFAIK. However, you can use [vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module to attempt to compile the code, and if it throws a SyntaxError before running, you'll see something like this. Running

```
console.log('I will throw') bar baz
```

results in a stack of

```
evalmachine.<anonymous>:1
console.log('I will throw') bar baz
                            ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInNewContext (vm.js:135:10)
    <etc>
```

So, just look at the first item in the stack to get the line number, and at the number of spaces before the `^` to get the column number. Using a similar technique as earlier, throw an error on the first line if parsing is successful:

```
const vm = require('vm');
const checkSyntax = (code) => {
  console.log('---------------------------');
  try {
    vm.runInNewContext(`throw new Error();\n${code}`);
  }
  catch (e) {
    describeError(e.stack);
  }
};
const describeError = (stack) => {
  const match = stack
    .match(/^\D+(\d+)\n(.+\n( *)\^+)\n\n(SyntaxError.+)/);
  if (!match) {
    console.log('Parse successful!');
    return;
  }
  const [, linenoPlusOne, caretString, colSpaces, message] = match;
  const lineno = linenoPlusOne - 1;
  const colno = colSpaces.length + 1;
  console.log(`${lineno}:${colno}: ${message}\n${caretString}`);
};


checkSyntax(`console.log('I will throw') bar baz`);
checkSyntax(`foo bar baz will throw too`);
checkSyntax(`console.log('A snippet without compile errors'); const foo = bar;`);
checkSyntax(`console.log('A multi line snippet');
With a syntax error on the second line`);
```

Result:

```
---------------------------
1:29: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
console.log('I will throw') bar baz
                            ^^^
---------------------------
1:5: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
foo bar baz will throw too
    ^^^
---------------------------
Parse successful!
---------------------------
2:6: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
With a syntax error on the second line
     ^
```

That said:

> How can I, without using external dependencies, pinpoint SyntaxError location withinn passed string? I require solution both for browser and nodejs.

Unless you *have* to achieve this without an external library, using a library really would be the easiest (and tried-and-tested) solution. Acorn, as shown earlier (and other parsers) work in Node as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sumarizing comments and some additional research:

## Simple anwer: currently impossible

There is currently no cross-platform way to retrive syntax error position from `new Function()` or `eval()` call.

## Partial solutions

1. Firefox support non-standard properties `error.lineNumber` and `error.e.columnNumber`. This can be used with feature detection if position of error is not critical.
2. There are filled bug reports/feature request for v8 that could bring support of (1) to chrome/node.js: Issue [#1281](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1281), [#1914](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1914), [#2589](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2589)
3. Use separate javascript parser, based on [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/).
4. Write custom javascript parser for the job.

Solutions 1 and 2 are incomplete, rely on features that are not part of standard. They can be suitable if this information is a help, not an requirement.

Solution 3 depends on external codebase, which was explicitly required by original question. It is suitable if this information is required and larger codebase is acceptable compromise.

Solution 4 is impractical.

Credits: @user3896470, @ivan-kuckir, @aprillion

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for browser:**

You can use latest Firefox to get the required information like error line number and column number inside the string.

Example:

```
  var testWithSyntaxError = "{\n\n\n\nvar x=3;\n =2;}";

  try {
      var f=new Function('',testWithSyntaxError);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e instanceof SyntaxError); 
    console.log(e.message);               
    console.log(e.name);                
    console.log(e.fileName);            
    console.log(e.lineNumber);           
    console.log(e.columnNumber);         
    console.log(e.stack);               
  }
```

Output in Firefox console:

```
  undefined
  true
  expected expression, got '='
  SyntaxError
  debugger eval code
  6
  1
  @debugger eval code:4:11
```

Where 6 is the line number and 1 is the column number of error inside the string.

It won't work in Chrome. There are bugs filed regarding this issue for chrome browser. See:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1281

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1914

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2589

Comment: I think provides.

Comment: Please add a star to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2589 to get , hopefully, this done by google team :-)

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic approximation, but it's possible to call `Function()` constructor on parts of the code (just to parse, without running) to see if the SyntaxError remains.

It seems that repeatedly removing lines from the end mostly works. This easily adds new syntax errors — e.g. can start code blocks {... and not finish ...} them — but normally the parser keeps reporting the earliest error. It's only when your remove the originally problematic line that the error changes/disappears.

Caveat with `Function()` constructor: it inserts `function anonymous(arg1, arg2` as line 1,
and `) {` as line 2 (see .toString() on successfully parsed functions).
This offsets all line numbers by 2!  The code below compensates for SyntaxError, but for any non-syntax exceptions it will affect numbers in `.stack` trace — those I didn't try to correct.

```js
// Firefox reports 1-based `lineNumber`, plus Function() prepends 2 lines.
// Measure instead of guessing!
let functionLineOffset = 0
try {
  Function('!@#$')
} catch (err) {
  functionLineOffset = err.lineNumber
}

// Uses `Function` constructor rules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function
//  - `code` should contain a `return` statement if you want a result.
//  - assignments without `var`/`let`/`const` do write to global namespace.
var betterEvalFunction = code => {
  let parsedFunc
  try {
    parsedFunc = new Function(code)
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
      // Goal: find & show responsible line directly in the message
      const {
        name,
        message,
        lineNumber,
        columnNumber
      } = err
      var lines = code.split('\n')

      // Firefox, non-standard
      if (lineNumber !== undefined) {
        const line = lineNumber - functionLineOffset
        throw SyntaxError(
          `${message} (at ${line + 1}:${columnNumber}):\n` +
          `${lines[line] || ''}\n` +
          (columnNumber === undefined ? '' : `${' '.repeat(columnNumber)}^`))
      }

      // Other browsers leave you in the dark :-(
      // ESTIMATE where it happened by slicing lines off the end until message disappears/changes
      // (likely to have unclosed braces etc. — but assuming it reports the first of all errors)
      var lastLine
      for (lastLine = lines.length - 1; lastLine > 0; lastLine--) {
        try {
          new Function(lines.slice(0, lastLine).join('\n')) // only parse, don't call
          console.log('error disappeared')
          break
        } catch (err2) {
          if (err2.message === err.message && err2 instanceof SyntaxError) {
            continue
          }
          console.log('error changed to:', err2.message)
          break
        }
      }
      throw SyntaxError(
        `${err.message} (probably around line ${lastLine + 1}):\n` +
        (lines[lastLine] || ''))
    }
    throw err
  }

  return parsedFunc()
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var testIt = code => {
  try {
    betterEvalFunction(code)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`)
  }
}

testIt(
` foo
  bar@baz
   .quux()
  another@error`)

testIt(
`{
  foo
  bar
   .quux()
  'opening { is unclosed'
`)

testIt(
` const x = 1
  // error disappears without the 2nd assignment
  const x = 2
`)

testIt(
` return [
    2,
    3,
    // error changes here — no !@# but now the [ is unclosed.
  ] !@#
  !@#
`)
```