# Mapping transpiled code back to the original markup script

Tags: javascript, algorithm, transpiler

Someone recently asked if there was a simple way to transform custom markup as follows, including nested markings.  Examples included...

- for `\k[hello]` the output will be `<b>hello</b>`
- for `\i[world]`, the output will be `<em>world</em>`
- for `hello \k[dear \i[world]]`, the output will be `hello <b>dear <em>world</em></b>`
- for `\b[some text](url)`, the output will be `<a href=”url”>some text</a>`
- for `\r[some text](url)`, the output will be `<img alt=”some text” src=”url” />`

Interestingly enough, transpiling the above to javascript, including consideration for nesting, is remarkably straightforward, particularly if the markup grammar is consistent.

```
//
// Define the syntax and translation to javascript.
//
const grammar = {

  syntax: {
    k:      {markUp: `\k[`, javascript: `"+grammar.oneArg("k","`,  pre: `<b>`,  post: `</b>`},
    i:      {markUp: `\i[`, javascript: `"+grammar.oneArg("i","`,  pre: `<em>`, post: `</em>`},
    b:      {markUp: `\b[`, javascript: `"+grammar.twoArgs("b","`, pattern: `<a href="$2">$1</a>`},
    r:      {markUp: `\r[`, javascript: `"+grammar.twoArgs("r","`, pattern: `<img alt="$1" src="$2"/>`},
    close0: {markUp: `](`,   javascript: `","`},
    close1: {markUp: `)`,    javascript: `")+"`},
    close2: {markUp: `]`,    javascript: `")+"`}
  },

  oneArg: function( command, arg1 ) {
    return grammar.syntax[ command ].pre + arg1 + grammar.syntax[ command ].post;
  },

  twoArgs: function( command, arg1, arg2 ) {
    return grammar.syntax[ command ].pattern.split( `$1` ).join( arg1 ).split( `$2` ).join( arg2 );
  }
}


function transpileAndExecute( markUpString ) {
  // Convert the markUp to javascript.
  for ( command in grammar.syntax ) {
    markUpString = markUpString.split( grammar.syntax[ command ].markUp ).join( grammar.syntax[ command ].javascript );
  }

  // With the markUp now converted to javascript, let's execute it!
  return new Function( `return "${markUpString}"` )();
}

var markUpTest = `Hello \k[dear \i[world!]] \b[\i[Search:] \k[Engine 1]](http://www.google.com) \r[\i[Search:] \k[Engine 2]](http://www.yahoo.com)`;

console.log( transpileAndExecute( markUpTest ) );
```

Note that there are obviously pre-processing issues that must also be addressed, such as how to handle the inclusion of tokens in normal text.  Eg, including a ']' as part of a text string will throw the transpiler a curve ball, so enforcing a rule such as using '\]' to represent a ']', and then replacing all such occurrences of '\]' with innocuous text before transpiling and then re-replacing afterwards solves this problem simply...

In terms of transpiling, using the grammar defined above, the following markup...

```
Hello \k[dear \i[world!]] \b[\i[Search:] \k[Engine 1]](http://www.google.com) \r[\i[Search:] \k[Engine 2]](http://www.yahoo.com)
```

...is transpiled to...

```
"Hello world! "+grammar.oneArg("k","dear "+grammar.oneArg("i","world")+"")+" "+grammar.twoArgs("b",""+grammar.oneArg("i","Search:")+" "+grammar.oneArg("k","Engine 1")+"","http://www.google.com")+" "+grammar.twoArgs("r",""+grammar.oneArg("i","Search:")+" "+grammar.oneArg("k","Engine 2")+"","http://www.yahoo.com")+""
```

...and once executed as a javascript Function, results in...

```
Hello <b>dear <em>world!</em></b> <a href="http://www.google.com"><em>Search:</em> <b>Engine 1</b></a> <img alt="<em>Search:</em> <b>Engine 2</b>" src="http://www.yahoo.com"/>
```

The real challenge though is the handling of syntax errors, particularly if one has large amounts of markup to transpile.  The crystal clear answer by CertainPerformance (see [Find details of SyntaxError thrown by javascript new Function() constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252731/find-details-of-syntaxerror-thrown-by-javascript-new-function-constructor) ) provides a means of capturing the line number and character number of a syntax error from a dynamically compiled javascript function, but am not quite sure of the best means of mapping a syntax error of the transpiled code back to the original markup.

Eg, if an extra ']' is out of place (after "Goodbye")...

```
Hello World! \b[\i[Goodbye]]] \k[World!]]
```

...this transpiles to...

```
"Hello World! "+grammar.twoArgs("b",""+grammar.oneArg("i","Goodbye")+"")+"")+" "+grammar.oneArg("k","World!")+"")+""
                                                                           ^
```

...and CertainPerformance's checkSyntax function returns "Error thrown at: 1:76", as expected, marked above with the "^".

The question is, how to map this back to the original markup to aid in narrowing down the error in the markup?  (Obviously in this case, it's simple to see the error in the markup, but if one has pages of markup being transpiled, then assistance in narrowing down the syntax error is a must.)  Maintaining a map between the markup and the transpiled code seems tricky, as the transpiler is mutating the markup to javascript code step-by-step as it walks the grammar transformation matrix.  My gut tells me there's a simpler way...  Thanks for looking.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Markdown. Markdown isn't "arbitrary markup". It's a specific language with a few common variants. I've removed the erroneous tag. Please take a moment to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: It gives reference error. ReferenceError: grammar is not defined

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the clarification.  Didn't realize markdown was reference to specific language.  Have modified question accordingly.  Will tweak code too after verifying changes.

Comment: @mirkancal, please ensure that the "const grammar = " is in the global scope, as the compilation of the transpiled function will need access to "grammar"i.  Now that I think about it, I suppose the grammar const can be included in the compilation, but something that would need some tinkering.

Comment: Just dawned on me that i can inject comments (ie, /*  */ ) into the transpiled code, with the idea of including the necessary information to reference back to the corresponding location in the markup.  Will tinker some more in the next day or so to see if this concept pans out in conjunction with CertainPerformance's checkSyntax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chased down the ability to leverage the javascript compiler to capture syntax errors in the transpiled code, and reference this back to the original markup.  In short, this involves a scheme of incorporating comments in the transpiled code to permit references back to the markup, providing the means of narrowing down the markup error.  (There is a bit of shortcoming in that the error message is really a transpiler syntax error, and doesn't necessarily correspond exactly to the markup error, but gives one a fighting chance to figure out where the markup issue lies.)

This algorithm also leverages the concepts of CertainPerformance's technique ( [Find details of SyntaxError thrown by javascript new Function() constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252731) ) of using setTimeout to capture the syntax errors of the transpiled code.  I have interspersed a javascript Promise to smooth the flow.

```
"use strict";

//
// Define the syntax and translation to javascript.
//
class Transpiler {

  static _syntaxCheckCounter = 0;
  static _syntaxCheck = {};
  static _currentSyntaxCheck = null;

  constructor() {
    this.grammar = {

      syntax: {
        k:      {markUp: `\k[`, javascript: `"►+grammar.oneArg("k",◄"`,  pre: `<b>`,  post: `</b>`},
        i:      {markUp: `\i[`, javascript: `"►+grammar.oneArg("i",◄"`,  pre: `<em>`, post: `</em>`},
        b:      {markUp: `\b[`, javascript: `"►+grammar.twoArgs("b",◄"`, pattern: `<a href="$2">$1</a>`},
        r:      {markUp: `\r[`, javascript: `"►+grammar.twoArgs("r",◄"`, pattern: `<img alt="$1" src="$2"/>`},
        close0: {markUp: `](`,   javascript: `"►,◄"`},
        close1: {markUp: `)`,    javascript: `"►)+◄"`},
        close2: {markUp: `]`,    javascript: `"►)+◄"`}
      },

      marker: {           // https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp
        begMarker: `►`,   // 25ba
        endMarker: `◄`,   // 25c4
        begComment: `◆`,  // 25c6
        endComment: `◇`,  // 25c7
        fillerChar: `●`   // 25cf
      },

      oneArg: function( command, arg1 ) {
        return this.syntax[ command ].pre + arg1 + this.syntax[ command ].post;
      },

      twoArgs: function( command, arg1, arg2 ) {
        return this.syntax[ command ].pattern.split( `$1` ).join( arg1 ).split( `$2` ).join( arg2 );
      }
    };
  };

  static transpilerSyntaxChecker(err) {
    // Uncomment the following line to disable default console error message.
    //err.preventDefault();

    let transpiledLine = Transpiler._syntaxCheck[ Transpiler._currentSyntaxCheck ].transpiledFunction.split(`\n`)[1];

    let lo = parseInt( transpiledLine.substr( transpiledLine.substr( 0, err.colno ).lastIndexOf( `●` ) + 1 ) );
    let hi = parseInt( transpiledLine.substr( transpiledLine.substr( err.colno ).indexOf( `●` ) + err.colno + 1 ) );

    let markUpLine = Transpiler._syntaxCheck[ Transpiler._currentSyntaxCheck ].markUp;
    let errString = markUpLine.substring( lo - 40, hi + 40 ).split(`\n`).join(`↵`) + `\n`;
    errString += ( `.`.repeat( lo ) + `^`.repeat( hi - lo ) ).substring( lo - 40, hi + 40 );

    Transpiler._syntaxCheck[Transpiler._currentSyntaxCheck].rejectFunction( new Error(`'${ err.message }' in transpiled code, corresponding to character range ${ lo }:${ hi } in the markup.\n${ errString }`) );

    window.removeEventListener('error', Transpiler.transpilerSyntaxChecker);
    delete Transpiler._syntaxCheck[Transpiler._currentSyntaxCheck];
  };

  async transpileAndExecute( markUpString ) {
    // Convert the markUp to javascript.

    console.log( markUpString );

    let gm = this.grammar.marker;
    let markUpIndex = markUpString;
    let transpiled = markUpString;
    for ( let n in this.grammar.syntax ) {
      let command = this.grammar.syntax[ n ];
      let markUpIndexSplit = markUpIndex.split( command.markUp );
      let transpiledSplit = transpiled.split( command.markUp );

      if ( markUpIndexSplit.length !== transpiledSplit.length ) {
        throw `Ambiguous grammar when searching for "${ command.markUp }" to replace with "${ command.javascript }".`;
      }

      for ( let i = 0; i < markUpIndexSplit.length; i++ ) {
        if ( i === 0 ) {
          markUpIndex = markUpIndexSplit[ 0 ];
          transpiled = transpiledSplit[ 0 ];
        } else {
          let js = command.javascript.replace( gm.begMarker, gm.begComment + gm.fillerChar + markUpIndex.length + gm.endComment );
          markUpIndex += gm.fillerChar.repeat( command.markUp.length );
          js = js.replace( gm.endMarker, gm.begComment + gm.fillerChar + markUpIndex.length + gm.endComment );
          markUpIndex += markUpIndexSplit[ i ];
          transpiled += js + transpiledSplit[ i ];
        }
      }
    };

    transpiled = transpiled.split( gm.begComment ).join( `/*` );
    transpiled = transpiled.split( gm.endComment ).join( `*/` );
    transpiled = `/*${ gm.fillerChar }0*/"${ transpiled }"/*${ gm.fillerChar }${ markUpIndex.length + 1 }*/`;

    console.log( markUpIndex );
    console.log( transpiled );

    let self = this;

    var id = ++Transpiler._syntaxCheckCounter;
    Transpiler._syntaxCheck[id] = {};

    let transpiledFunction = `"use strict"; if ( run ) return\n${ transpiled.split(`\n`).join(` `) }`;
    Transpiler._syntaxCheck[id].markUp = markUpString;
    Transpiler._syntaxCheck[id].transpiledFunction = transpiledFunction;

    //
    // Here's where it gets tricky.  (See "CertainPerformance's" post at
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252731
    // for details behind the concept.)  In this implementation a Promise
    // is created, which on success of the JS compiler syntax check, is resolved
    // immediately.  Otherwise, if there is a syntax error, the transpilerSyntaxChecker
    // routine, which has access to a reference to the Promise reject function,
    // calls the reject function to resolve the promise, returning the error back
    // to the calling process. 
    // 
    let checkSyntaxPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout( () => {
        Transpiler._currentSyntaxCheck = id;
        window.addEventListener('error', Transpiler.transpilerSyntaxChecker);

        // Perform the syntax check by attempting to compile the transpiled function.
        new Function( `grammar`, `run`, transpiledFunction )( self.grammar );

        resolve( null );
        window.removeEventListener('error', Transpiler.transpilerSyntaxChecker);
        delete Transpiler._syntaxCheck[id];
      });
      Transpiler._syntaxCheck[id].rejectFunction = reject;
    });

    let result = await checkSyntaxPromise;

    // With the markUp now converted to javascript and syntax checked, let's execute it!
    return ( new Function( `grammar`, `run`, transpiledFunction.replace(`return\n`,`return `) )( this.grammar, true ) );

  };

}
```

Here are some sample runs with botched markup, and the corresponding console output.  The following markup has an extra `]`...

```
let markUp = `Hello World \k[Goodbye]] World`;
new Transpiler().transpileAndExecute( markUp ).then(result => console.log( result )).catch( err => console.log( err ));
```

...resulting in transpiled code of...

```
/*●0*/""/*●0*/+grammar.oneArg("i",/*●2*/"Hello World"/*●13*/)+/*●14*/" "/*●15*/+grammar.oneArg("k",/*●17*/""/*●17*/+grammar.oneArg("i",/*●19*/"Goodbye"/*●26*/)+/*●27*/" World"/*●34*/
```

Note the interspersed comments, which point back to the character position in the original markup.  Then, when the javascript compiler throws an error, it is trapped by `transpilerSyntaxChecker` which uses the embedded comments to identify the location in the markup, dumping the following results to the console...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at markUp.html:127
Error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )' in transpiled code, corresponding to character range 22:23 in the markup.
Hello World k[Goodbye]] World
......................^
    at transpilerSyntaxChecker (markUp.html:59)
```

Note that the `Unexpected token )` message refers to the transpiled code, not the markup script, but the output points to the offending `]`.

Here's another sample run, in this case missing a close `]`...

```
let markUp = `\i[Hello World] \k[\i[Goodbye] World`;
new Transpiler().transpileAndExecute( markUp ).then(result => console.log( result )).catch(err => console.log( err ));
```

...which produces the following transpiled code...

```
/*●0*/""/*●0*/+grammar.oneArg("i",/*●2*/"Hello World"/*●13*/)+/*●14*/" "/*●15*/+grammar.oneArg("k",/*●17*/""/*●17*/+grammar.oneArg("i",/*●19*/"Goodbye"/*●26*/)+/*●27*/" World"/*●34*/
```

...throwing the following error...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at markUp.html:127
Error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' in transpiled code, corresponding to character range 27:34 in the markup.
i[Hello World] k[i[Goodbye] World
...........................^^^^^^^
    at transpilerSyntaxChecker (markUp.html:59)
```

Maybe not the best solution, but a lazy man's solution. Tschallacka's response has merit (ie, a custom syntax checker or using something like Jison) in performing a true syntax check against the markup, without the setTimeout / Promise complexities nor the somewhat imprecise method of using the transpiler error messages to refer to the original markup...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you write a syntax checker, kinda like jsonlint or jslint etc... that checks if everything is checked and closed properly, before actually compiling the text to human readable text.

This allows for debugging, and prevents from malformed code running haywire, and allows you to provide an error highlighted document editor when they are editing the text.

Below a proof of concept which just checks if brackets are closed properly.

```js
var grammarLint = function(text) {
  var nestingCounter = 0;
  var isCommand = char => char == '\\';
  var isOpen = char => char == '[';
  var isClose = char => char == ']';
  var lines = text.split('\n');
  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    text = lines[i];
    for(var c = 0; c < text.length; c++) {
     var char = text.charAt(c);
     if(isCommand(char) && isOpen(text.charAt(c+2))) {
        c += 2;
        nestingCounter++;
        continue;
     }
     if(isClose(char)) {
        nestingCounter--;
        if(nestingCounter < 0) {
            throw new Error('Command closed but not opened at on line '+(i+1)+' char '+(c+1));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(nestingCounter > 0) {
     throw new Error(nestingCounter + ' Unclosed command brackets found');
  }
}
text = 'Hello World! \\b[\\i[Goodbye]]] \\k[World!]]';
try {
   grammarLint(text);
}
catch(e) {
   console.error(e.message);
}
text = 'Hello World! \\b[\\i[Goodbye \\k[World!]]';
try {
   grammarLint(text);
}
catch(e) {
   console.error(e.message);
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting the suggestion.  am hoping to use the "checkSyntax" function to leverage the javascript compiler to capture a wide range of potential errors beyond balanced parenthesis, brackets, quotes, etc, but will certainly consider this a fallback position, as these types of syntax errors are probably the most prevalent.