# Check string contains JavaScript code or normal string?

Tags: javascript, string

There is a situation to run code inside javascript string. But there is two possibilities that the string can contain a javascript or not. So I want to check first is there any javascript code before executing the string.

```
let code = "alert('Run Run')";
let runFunction = new Function(code);
runFunction();
```

I tried regex apporach, but it would not work.

```
let exists = code.match(/[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/) ? "YES" : "NO";
```

Is there any way to check this.

Comment: I assume you will be running some for of `eval` on the input `code`. So how about `try-catch` the call to `eval(code)` and let javascript handle it?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Unfortunately, `try/catch` does *not* catch syntax errors in evaluated strings (or `new Function`s) - you have to add an error listener to the window for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can [check the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252731/find-details-of-syntaxerror-thrown-by-javascript-new-function-constructor/55555357#55555357) of the string to see if it can be parsed properly before running it for real, though this essentially just involves attempting to execute the string as Javascript anyway.

```js
const stringIsJS = (str) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (errorEvent) => {
    // Don't pollute the console with additional info:
    errorEvent.preventDefault();
    resolve(errorEvent.reason.message === 'No syntax problems');
  }, { once: true });
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    eval('throw new Error("No syntax problems");' + str);
  });
});

(async () => {
  console.log(
    await stringIsJS('hello hello'),
    await stringIsJS('const foo = "bar";'),
  );
})();
```

`throw new Error` is inserted at the top of the code to be evaluated to ensure that the `stringIsJS` only checks the syntax of the string, rather than actually running any substantive code.

Or, using Acorn:

```js
const stringIsJS = (str) => {
  try {
    acorn.Parser.parse(str);
    return true;
  } catch(e){
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(
  stringIsJS('hello hello'),
  stringIsJS('const foo = "bar";'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/acorn@6.1.1/dist/acorn.min.js"></script>
```

(still, this is a very weird thing to have to determine programmatically - it would be much better to, for example, save an additional flag in a database to indicate whether a particular string is Javascript or not)