# Javascript : 'Compilation' error position on new Function('...my code as string')

Tags: javascript

We've some user defined fields defining javascript functions and would like to show the user the position ( line, column ) when an 'compilation' error is thrown. For example :

```
userFunc = new Function('context',  '{  let a = 0; \n this <-> is not Javascript; return 2; }');
```

an exception is thrown, that looks like :

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
```

The line information is lost, is there any way or library to retrieve line information ?

Comment: No, by the time the `Function` constructor runs, the arguments are just strings.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55555357 - add an error listener to the window

Comment: @CertainPerformance , thank . It's asynchronous not really what I was looking for. Tricky if you've several of those one in the same thread and we need to check how to put this in a react/redux framework. A real pain Chrome team is not implementing this (sometimes they are really stubborn ;-) ). For now,  looking at parsers as Acorn